# What does the `close()` method of the Mysqli Statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

Can someone tell me, when you for example update, insert, delete.. should you then close it like [`mysqli_stmt::close();`](http://www.php.net/mysqli_stmt.close) ? I checked PHP manual and don't understand what `close()` actually does.

Example:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `user_email` FROM `users` WHERE `user_email` = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array($email));
$stmt->close();
```

Next part of my question is, if as an example i had multiple update queries in a **transaction** after every `execute()` for each query i am executing within the **transaction** should i close them individually ? ... because it's a transaction not sure i need to use `$stmt->close();` after each execute(); or just use one `$stmt->close();` after all of them ?

Comment: What `close` method are you referring to? There is only `PDOStatement::closeCursor` that has a similar name...

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046614/do-sql-connections-opened-with-pdo-in-php-have-to-be-closed

Comment: @Jon i got confused, i replied to comments below, thanks phplover

Comment: For those who are looking for a [PHP function to close the **Mysql** connection with PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14113114/367456), it's in an answer to a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using mysqli close method. The $stmt->close() methode simply just closes closes the the previous opened database connect (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php).

**EDIT:** If it's PDO you are using, I simply do not understand, why you dont take advantage of the possibility of having named parametres instead of question marks. That is, why a lot of people choose PDO instead of mysqli - you might have a better comprehensive view of the queries/statements.

Comment: i am new to pdo and saw it somewhere $stmt->close() and thought it meant close the prepared statement and $stmt = null will close the connection, so basically you only use $stmt->close() if using the mysqli procedural style ? (ie. i would not use $stmt->close() on example statement i gave in my original post) ? instead i would use $stmt = null; to close the connection to db ? thanks phplover

Comment: Not exactly. $stmt->close() is for mysqli OOP style, mysql_close or mysqli_close is the mysql(i) procedural style. And yes, to close the connection to the database in PDO, you simply set the statement to NULL.

Comment: named parameters or questions marks is a matter of personal choice to what i have learnt, i just find question marks easier peronsally for myself plus my reason for moving from mysql_ to PDO was for the security benefits and because mysql_ is getting old now and i want to learn and keep upto date, i not learnt OOP yet but will do once i learn PDO to its full glory, thanks phplover

Comment: That's right, it is a matter of personal choice. I don't use PDO myself, but I have read a lot about it. As far as I am concerned, the level of security or the level of effectivity is pretty much the same for PDO and mysqli. There will probably within 2 years come a new API for mysql, which hopefully will be improved even more. The main benefits of choosing PDO over mysqli, as I see it, is the named parameters and that PDO can run on 12 different drivers. Otherwise I don't see, why peoeple don't just use mysqli - lot of the methods are pretty much alike the old mysql API.

Comment: But yes, it surely is a matter of personal choice what to choose between PDO and mysqli.

Comment: here are two links that's worth a read on differences etc. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/ and http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/

Comment: But is it necessary to close the previous opened database connection? I have posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164371/php-prepare-method-not-working-when-calling-it-twice a problem, where everything breaks if I do not close it and I dont understand why, because I have not found that it is obligatory to close a prepare statement before calling a 2nd.

Answer (score 8):

There is no close() method for PDO, instead to close a connection you just set the database variable to null - which will close the connection.

```
$stmt = null;
```

To answer your second question, you only need to close the connection once. After you've executed all the queries you need to do on the database.