# PHP Prepare method not working when calling it twice?

Tags: php

I am using the prepare method as follows:

```
$db= new mysqli("localhost","***","***","***");

if ($db->connect_error) {
  die('Connection Error');
}

$id = 1;
if($stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = ? '))
{
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
  $stmt->execute();
  // $stmt->close();
  echo "Success<br>";
}
else {
  echo "Something broke :/<br>";
}

$id =2;
if($stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = ? '))
{
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
  $stmt->execute();
  echo "Success<br>";
}
else {
  echo "Something broke :/<br>";
  $error = $db->errno . ' ' . $db->error;
  echo $error;
}
```

If I execute the script I get

> Success
>
> Something broke :/
>
> 0

How can I find out why the prepare method failed, after it gets called a second time? For some reason, `$db->errno` returns 0, which indicates that nothing went wrong. However, the prepare methods failes and returns false, so I cannot check `$stmt->error;`

I found out by accident that when I remove the first `$stmt->execute()` call, then calling the prepare method again works fine (At its first and second call). What am I missing here?

**Edit**

As suggested by Maxim Tkach if I uncomment

```
// $stmt->close();
```

then I get

> Success
>
> Success

But why is that? I have never read anywhere that it is crucial to close a prepare statement.

This is from the PHP Manual:

> Closes a prepared statement. mysqli_stmt_close() also deallocates the
> statement handle. If the current statement has pending or unread
> results, this function cancels them so that the next query can be
> executed.

I do not see that they say its crucial to close in order to execute a second prepare statement. Am I missing something?

Comment: `if(!$stmt->execute()){ trigger_error("There was an error.... ".$db->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` ? is this what the question's about? and possibly http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- no I already get an error when calling the bind_param method.

Comment: what is it exactly that you want to do Adam? I guess I'm not grasping the question. Can you elaborate on it? Do you need to log the error and catch exactly what caused the error(s)? If so, then you should have logs to look at. Wait for someone else to see if they have a better understanding of your question.

Comment: Use `print_r($stmt->error_list);` to check number of error  from the last statement executed

Comment: @Saty that gives me  `Trying to get property of non-object in`

Comment: Paste your full code along with your connection!!

Comment: I still don't know what the question's about; *sorry*.

Comment: @Saty I have edited my question and gave the full code. As it turns out, the prepare statement is executed once correctly, and when I call it a second time it fails.

Comment: @Fred-ii- me neither :p

Comment: @Fred-ii- My question is: How can I find out why the prepare method fails? All error messages that I could produce were very strange.

Comment: shouldn't be $db->errorInfo?

Comment: @Jack no this property only exist for a PDO object, but I have a mysqli object.

Comment: @Adam, looks like a legitimate question to me, but you could improve it by incorporating the "edits" into the proper flow of the question. In other words: Try rewriting the question from scratch, using what you know by now. Provide a short script (no loop, since you know if fails on exactly the second time), and the outputs.

Comment: Write for `prepare statement` outside the `foreach loop` and `bind_param and execute statemen` inside `foreach loop.`

Comment: @alexis okay I will do this. Is there a possibility to hide the question until I have edit it correctly?

Comment: [*Did you not use this as I suggested earlier?...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164371/php-how-to-find-prepare-error#comment61864260_37164371) you should be getting specific errors  here, which is what I use all the time.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have edited the question, I hope its more clear now. I have not used `if(!$stmt->execute())` because the error appears earlier.

Comment: @Adam you're right. apologize

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need read this: [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

> The prepared statement execution consists of two stages: prepare and
> execute. At the prepare stage a statement template is sent to the
> database server. The server performs a syntax check and initializes
> server internal resources for later use.

and

> Every prepared statement occupies server resources. Statements should
> be closed explicitly immediately after use. If not done explicitly,
> the statement will be closed when the statement handle is freed by
> PHP.

After reading the article, i concluded:
**You can not prepare a query, without closing the previous one. Always be prepared to close the inquiry, after the execution**.

And your code should be rewritten as follows:

```
$db= new mysqli("localhost","***","***","***");
if ($db->connect_error) {   
      die('Connection Error'); 
}
$id = 1; 
if($stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = ? ')) { 
      $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);   
      $stmt->execute(); 
      echo "Success<br>"; 
} else {   
       echo "Something broke :/<br>"; 
}

$id = 2;
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

**P.S If you add the check return value of bind and execute - it will be good**

Answer (score 2):

You need read $stmt->error;

To read, you need rewrite code as in the example below.

```
...
$stmt = new mysqli_stmt($db);
if($stmt->prepare('SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = ? '))
{
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
  $stmt->execute();
  echo "Success<br>";
}
else {
  var_dump($stmt->error);
}
...
```

Comment: If the prepare statement fails, then it returns false. So I cannot access`$stmt->error` in the else clause, because its a boolean. However I just noticed that if I call `$stmt = new mysqli_stmt($db)`, after `$id=2` then I the second prepare statement does not fail. Still - I dont know why the second prepared statement fails in my script and how to get access to an error message.

Comment: Maybe you need call $stmt->close(); after first request?

Comment: You are right, if I call `$stmt->close()` after the first request it works (However, I do not need to initialize $stmt beforehand) . But why? I do not find in the manual that it is obligatory to close a prepare statement. I adjusted my question.