# Prepared statement, is this written correctly?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've been investing the time to learn Prepared Statements in MySQLi. I'm using PHP Solutions Second Edition by David Powers as a reference.

This query pulls a random photo filename from a specific gallery. The gallery number is a variable ($i). This is working, I simply want to know if it is written properly. My websites are fairly simple but I want to avoid SQL injection.

```
$conn = dbConnect('query');
$randPic = "SELECT p_fname
        FROM photos
        WHERE g_id = ?
        ORDER by RAND()
        LIMIT 1";
$gid = $i;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($randPic);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $gid);
$stmt->bind_result($p_fname);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();
```

On the page where the random photo is needed, I am able to call it by the variable:

```
echo $p_fname;
```

And again, it all works. I just want to know if this is coded properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your query is written fine.

Be careful when you output data.  If outputting variable data for an HTML page, use `htmlspecialchars()` to avoid accidentally injecting HTML into your pages.

Comment: Brad, many thanks to you! The value contained in $p_fname is simply a filename. There's still plenty of PHP I need to learn, can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Also...I read that after such a query, I should use either free_result() or  close() but am not getting a good idea as to which one is best. Any advice would be gratefully received. Thanks!

Comment: @wordman, The risk is very low for file names, but it is good practice to follow in any case.  As an example, suppose you were outputting some text that had a quote mark `"` in it.  Your HTML could look something like:  `<img alt="Image for "something"" />`  This confuses the parser, and is not valid HTML.  Using `htmlspecialchars()` will change that output to `<img alt="Image for &quot;something&quot;" />`

Comment: @wordman, If your script doesn't do much after running that query, there really isn't a need to close anything.  Your script will end, and memory will be freed automatically.  See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046614/do-sql-connections-opened-with-pdo-in-php-have-to-be-closed

Comment: That's exactly the type of explanation I needed, thank you! I'll have to do some additional research on this topic.

Comment: @Brad...I updated my original question with another query. I'm flying by the seat of my pants with this one.

Comment: @wordman, Post new questions as new questions.  That's what keeps StackOverflow organized.

Comment: I thought as much. Deleted and posted as new. Thanks!