# How do I close an SQLite database opened with OOP method?

Tags: php, sqlite

When opening an SQLite database using procedural code, PHP provides the [sqlite_close()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-close.php) function to close it again; but when using the OOP methods, I can't find an equivalent option. Is it simply a case of unsetting the SQLite object, or am I missing an alternative close option?

Comment: I gather moving to PDO is not an option? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1046624/59087)

Comment: This is an option for an OS library, I also offer SQLite3 as an option, but I really need SQLite as an alternative for users who don't have SQLite3 or PDO available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to online source code: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/sqlite/sqlite.c#534 close option in OOP is not available. And even if one uncomments this and recompiles this module, it will still fail: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/sqlite/sqlite.c#1763 but this time with helpful error - destroing an object is a way to go.