# MySQL Too many connections error using Laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, mariadb

I have a Laravel 5.4 web app running on a shared hosting ([a2hosting](https://www.a2hosting.com/)) and once every now and then I get a `SQLSTATE[08004][1040] Too many connections` error. Some times it takes a few minutes to start working again, some times it has taken hours.

I have tried several things to diagnose the problem and to try to fix it but nothing has worked so far.

`max_connections` is set to 500 and `wait_timeout` is set to 8 hours.

If I log in into the mysql cli while the error is still poping out and list the active processes it show's no more than 10 ~ 15 processes.

Also the system is only used by some 30 people so I have no idea why the max number of connections could be reached (maybe php is not closing some connections for some reason?).

Has anyone encountered an error like this? and if so what have you done to fix it?
Also any ideas of what could be causing the error and how to prevent/fix it?

I can provide more info on my laravel app, db, and server if it could help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225164/sqlstatehy000-1040-too-many-connections

Comment: Try raising `max_user_connections` value also.

Answer (score 1):

Possible causes:

- "Connection pooling" is turned on (somewhere), and set too high.
- The Web server has too many 'children'; lower its limit.
- There may be 'slow' queries that need optimizing.
- The connections fail to 'disconnect' when finished.
- Decrease, not increase, `wait_timeout`.
- There are multiple `wait_timeout` settings; you changed the wrong one.
- Increasing the number of simultaneous connections can make the overall performance worse.