# Too many conenctions error on AWS-EC2 (Laravel, MySQL) - SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040]

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-ec2

I want to handle 1000 to 10000 Async requests at a time & each request consists of 2 MySQL queries. Problem is that the server is able to handle the request(confirmed through the https logs) but unable to process it due to "Too many connections error".

Questions:

1. Should I increase the "Max user connections" for MySQL & increase the necessary hardware (or) Should I contact DB admin?
2. How to handle this error? (I am unable to connect to the server when this error occurred to restart the MySQL & it is not coming back to the normal state until I restart the whole server)

> I am currently struct with this situation, If anyone has an idea about one of these questions alone, Please answer so that it can be a head's up for the remaining ones. Since I am a developer, It will be the last option to go with paid AWS support.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24225501/2671470

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur Tried it & kept on increasing the number each time this problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to review your app architecture.

If I were you, and instead of trying to process all the requests at the same time, I'd do the following:
- each time the app receives a request, I'll dispatch a job that will execute those SQL request.
- I'll have multiple background workers processing those jobs, and I'll limit the number of parallel process to how many the DB can handle.

this way, you'll ensure that all requests all processed without doing it all at the exact same time

for more information:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues

Comment: Its a "GET" request & it need to fetch/update data from MySQL for each request, I will completely agree with you if it's a "POST" or "PUT" requests

Comment: do you need to execute the requests right away? what would happen if you do it asynchronously in a job?

Comment: Yes that is the whole issue about, I want to execute it right away