# pdo connection wont close once statements have been executed

Tags: php, pdo

Using PHP 5.5, I've noticed that I cannot close PDO connections after I've already executed statements using a connection.

For instance:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$dbh = null;
```

Closes the connection just fine.  But I can't get the following connection to close here:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select * from someTable where 1<>0");
$stmt->execute();
$dbh = null;
```

Comment: Try putting this after your connection: `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`. I have a hunch it's because you're not fetching all the rows. If that's the case, you'll need to do a `fetchAll()` before you can close the connection.

Comment: Why do you want to close it anyway? Shouldn't it be more efficient to let it stay open?

Comment: My company is using Doctrine 1.2 in a daemonized job worker and somehow my query results are getting cached somewhere.  I'm trying to restart my database connection in order to wipe out my Doctrine_Manager instance.  Essentially this:  http://thoughtworker.in/2012/09/29/symfony-worker-tasks/

Comment: Josh, you forgot to ping @Vilx-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a related note about this on the PHP docs here http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php#114822.  In short, you need to set the statement and the connection to null.

```
$stmt = null;
$dbh = null;
```

Comment: So essentially I have to go through my entire codebase and find where i'm using PDO statements and null them out when I'm done with them just to kill the connection?  There has to be a better way...

Comment: Well why do you want to close the connection every time you use it?

Comment: @JoshNankin Someone wrote a [function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14113114/811240) to do it.

Comment: @Reeling see my comment on question

Comment: @JoshNankin sorry I don't know anything about Doctrine.  Wouldn't it be better to figure out more about the cache instead of working around it?

Comment: Believe me, I'm trying :).  At this point I'm just trying to get something to work.

Comment: hehe alright.  Sorry I can't really help with that. best of luck :)

Comment: @JoshNankin Maybe the part on persistent connections here would help you too: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: If you use OOP or at least functions (not global scope), references to `$stmt` should already be unset after usage.

Comment: was able to solve my doctrine problem with Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->connection()->clear();

Answer (score 1):

I'm making an educated guess here that `$stmt` also has an indirect reference to `$dbh`, since it needs it to fetch data and stuff. Try nulling that too.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your database object, and create a __destruct method to close the statement.  Careful, I did not test the code below.

```
class MyPDO extends \PDO
{
    protected $db;
    protected $stm;

    public function __construct($conn_string,$user,$password)
    {
        $opts = [
              \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true // careful, if connection fails to close, "has gone away" may appear on the next connection.
            , \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true
            , \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
        ];
        $this->db =  new \PDO($conn_string, $user, $password, $opts);
    }

    public function prepare($query,$options = [])
    {
        $this->stm = $this->db->prepare($query,$options);
        return $this->stm;
    }

    public function close()
    {
        if(is_object($this->stm))
        {
            $this->stm->closeCursor();
        }
        $this->stm = null;
        $this->db = null;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->close();
    }
}

$dbh = new MyPDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare(...);
$stmt->execute();
$dbh = null; // this should call the __destruct method, and ensure everything is closed properly
```

Comment: You might consider rolling back any open transactions too. If they have not been committed by the time the connection is being closed, chances are something went wrong and you do not want the transaction hanging around.